# How to find out if an object has or has not been collected?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

1) Is there a tool that tells you whether a specific object has been garbage collected or not?

2) Is there a way to see what all objects are in which gc queue at a given point in time?

I remember seeing a Channel 9 video some 5 - 6 years ago where two guys were demo-ing cordbg or mdbg, the debuggers on the command line and they were showing the garbage collection data.

Comment: The only way something can be GCed is if there are no references to it.  Any method you'd have to check if the object is still alive *would be keeping it alive*.  There also *is no* queue of objects to be GCed.  The objects are murdered as soon as it is determined that they shouldn't be kept alive, all at once, instantly.  Sounds like you should just read up on GC a bit to learn the basics of how they work.

Comment: @Servy: He doesn't seem to want to do this in code, from what I can tell. He wants some kind of tool... Why, I can't imagine. That's against the rules here. Besides, any time you're trying to think about what's getting garbage collected, you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: CLR Memory Diagnostics is a managed API that wraps previously internal-only CLR debugging APIs. It is available from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime). You may be able to use it to acquire the information you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks very much, @mikez and CodeCaster for the help.

Comment: Hi @Servy: What's an f-reachable queue and what are the different generations that GC marks objects into?

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 Again, sounds like you're better off going and getting a book about the GC to read to just learn the basics.

Comment: If GC is working correctly, you shouldn't ever be aware that it is going on. What is your *real* problem, the reason that makes you ask this? Write that up as a new question, please.

Comment: @vonbrand I have an application with 800+ tables and 40 monkeys. I wrote most of the cross-cutting concerns and a mediator that sits between the Entity Framework ObjectContext and the EMDX's ObjectContext derived class. I use my go-between-class to propagate entity-tracking related events. 40 monkeys write views and controller actions. The monstrous app is leaking like a steamy pipe. I want to know if its my code or monkey code and then I want to clean up. The ASP.NET application pool restarts every 5 hours or so.

Answer (score -1):

While this might be a possible duplicate, and there are already a few answers, you can always use the [WeakReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class in .NET to track when an object has been garbage collected!

Comment: Downvoter: Why?

Edit: He's looking for a tool, not a class. Whoops.